# Import values from database to a select

Tags: php, css, mysql, html

Good morning;

I´m trying to load some values from a mysql database to a "select", inside a form with HTML, PHP and some javascript.

[image]

I´m doing a school project and I need some names that are registered on the database. When I click on the select i want them to appear, so I can register one class and give them a class director (i´m not sure if that is called like that in english). When I "edit" the class, i want the select to put the value that are on the database and I want it to let me change the value.

[image]

I have a function file that help me with the functions that I use on the website, and I made de select code like this.

```
function DBConnect ()
{
    $db = mysqli_connect (DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die (mysqli_connect_error());
    return $db;
}

function DBClose($db)
{
    mysqli_close($db) or die (mysqli_error($db));
}

function DBExecute($sql)
{
    $db = DBConnect();
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    DBClose($db);
    return $result;
}

function DBRead11()
{
    $sql="SELECT nome FROM user_especial";
    $result=DBExecute($sql);

    while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dts[]=$res;
    }
    return $dts;
}
```

And the code that I used on the php page so the select could "spawn" the values is this one:

```
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
    <?php echo $dts; ?>
</select>
```

My database looks like the table that I puted on the first imgur link.
Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: can you do echo var_dump($dts);die; before it goes to HTML? and share it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your problem correctly the issue is that `$dts` is not known in the HTML select element because it is only in the function scope of `DBRead11`. Therefore, before getting the value of `$dts`, you need to call the function `DBRead11()` and save the returned value into `$dts`. After that, because the array `$dts` should contain the attribute `nome` of all rows in the database, you can loop through all entries of `$dts` (e.g. with `foreach()`) and construct a HTML option element from the value at the specific index.

In addition to that, I think you need to initialize `$dts` in your `DBRead11` function as `$dts = array()` or `$dts = []` before adding values to it.

```php
function DBRead11() {
  $sql="SELECT nome FROM user_especial";
  $result=DBExecute($sql);

  $dts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  return $dts;
  }
```

```
<?php $dts = DBRead11(); ?>
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
  <?php
    foreach($dts as $option) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>"><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

As @M.Hemant already asked, please provide a `var_dump()` of the `$dts` variable. Otherwise, I can't tell exactly if just outputting `$option` (every a single element of $dts) is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, i was waiting for the `var_dump` because it is not clear if `$option` alone will work. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: I tryed to make the change, to show you the var_dump but this error appeard:
https://imgur.com/a/96FDhD7 
That you.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up something. It should be `foreach($dts as $option) {}`.

Comment: This append https://imgur.com/a/Pj3ExSZ  I´m not sure if I did it in the correct way...

Comment: `$dts` is only available in the scope of function `DBRead11()`. You need to save the return value of this function to `$dts` before using it in the `foreach()` like so `<?php $dts = DBRead11(); ?>`. I added this part to my example above.

Comment: This append https://imgur.com/a/WrEqgHg , on the first image ou can see one option, but it have a second one with the same value "array".

Comment: Yes, this what I've expected. Instead of a var_dump, you could also write a `print_r($dts);` and share this content here. Do it for example right before the `foreach()`.

Comment: Here it is https://imgur.com/a/12YkzdU it gave me an error: [11-Apr-2019 10:05:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/donutsro/public_html/gestao_turmas.php on line 84

Comment: I edited my code above to avoid unnecessary nested arrays. Now in `DBRead11()` the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is directly written into `$dts` and now you should be able to access every row from your database table in `$option` as key-value pairs. Because you are only selecting the attribute `nome` in your SQL statement, you are only able to access `$option['nome']` that equals the corresponding attribute.

Comment: The "Array to string conversion" error is because foreach only takes the first "array level" and writes every element of it to `$option` -> `$option` is an array again. With my fixed code it should be a string and fine now.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope my explanation was easy to understand. Please flag this answer as accepted and feel free to ask further questions.